# use chain methods on inherted struct

Tags: go

I'm new to Go. I'm solving a problem which is similarity to this, I have a struct Dog inherited from Animal struct. I want to chain method so that i could get a result like "I am an animal. woof!" but when i run the program, it generate an error

> dog.Animal.Hello().Bark undefined (type *Animal has no field or method Bark)

```
type Animal struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func (animal *Animal) Hello() *Animal {
    fmt.Println("I am an animal")
    return animal
}

type Dog struct {
    *Animal
}

func (dog *Dog) Bark() *Dog {
    fmt.Println("woof!")
    return dog
}

func main() {
    dog := &Dog{&Animal{name: "Peter", age: 25}}
    dog.Hello().Bark()
}
```

How can i get over this. Thank you for any recommendation

Comment: Go doesn't have the classical inheritance like that of Java. It has composition and the way in which you design class hierarchies are different. The way your code looks, you have a `Dog` which **HAS** an `Animal`. This is not the same as a `Dog` **IS** an `Animal`.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at interfaces in Go. One possible way of doing this is to create an `Animal` interface that can `MakeNoise()`.

Answer (score 1):

`dog.Hello()` returns an `*Animal`, not a `*Dog`, so you can't just call `.Bark()` on the returned value.

Note that the call `dog.Hello()` doesn't *really* call `Hello()` on the `Dog` struct, but rather on the `*Animal` contained within. It's just syntactic sugar, equivalent to `dog.animal.Hello()` (if the `*Animal` field were named, instead of anonymous). It is not inheritance!

However, you already have a `*Dog` so you can just call `.Bark()` on that directly:

```
dog.Hello()
dog.Bark()
```

Suggestions in the comments about interfaces might also apply, but with this toy example, it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve in the first place.